# multi stage booting

Tags: linux-kernel, arm, u-boot

I have one board with working u-boot flashed on it. Now I want to add some functionality to the bootloader (for initializing some part of the hardware), But the development process may brick the board if I make some mistake. 
Is it possible to do multi stage booting mentioned as below:
1) start u-boot
2) u-boot will load my binary, which has added functionality to initialize hardware.
3) my binary will load and boot the linux-kernel.

If it is possible, some pointers will be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Too much work!  You have created an XY problem.  Might be simpler to load a "sub-program" using the `go` command, and continue to use U-Boot to load the kernel.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15340089/how-to-run-custom-kernel-on-beaglebone/15375308#15375308  Eventually you should incorporate this new board-initialization code into U-Boot.

Comment: Thanks! I think I need to use "go" command.

Comment: You would probably use the U-Boot `go` command for either a next-stage bootloader or a sub-program.

Answer (score 2):

Yes.  Multi-stage boot is commonly used on ARM SoCs.

In the case of TI OMAP devices, as an example,  two instances of the boot-loader are used.  The first is run without any expectations that the SDRAM is initialised, and is copied into 
and executed from 48kB of embedded SRAM.  Necessarily, it doesn't do much besides some basic hardware initialisation (e.g. SDRAM, enabling power to certain functional units, enabling clocks) and then loading the second-stage boot-loader.  Even this is a tight fit.

The u-Boot (and also [Barebox](http://barebox.org), and probably other bootloader) source-trees have build options to build this set-up, which I'm sure you could subvert.

You might be better off modifying an existing boot-loader.  I have good experiences of using [Barebox](http://barebox.org) for this.

In the case of OMAP, the first boot-loader is generally referred to as `MLO` - this might help in finding resources.

Comment: Thanks for answering. I dont have tools for flashing bootloader for now. So currently only way to proceed is to develop another binary, that will work as another stage of bootloader after u-boot.

Comment: flashing a boot-loader a slightly nerve-wracking experience the first time - however, most systems have a number of primary boot options, so you usually have a get-out-of-jail free card rather than a bricked board.