# U-Boot: Application crashes - but why

Tags: u-boot, lego-mindstorms

I'm trying to get a stand-alone application for U-Boot running.

Target is a LEGO EV3 brick - it has an TI OMAP (ARM9) CPU.

The output of U-Boot before hanging is:

```
U-Boot > fatload mmc 0:1 c0007FC0 uimage
reading uimage

384 bytes read
U-Boot > bootm
## Booting kernel from Legacy Image at c0007fc0 ...
   Image Name:   ITK EV3 sample OS
   Image Type:   ARM Linux Standalone Program (uncompressed)
   Data Size:    320 Bytes =  0.3 kB
   Load Address: c0008000
   Entry Point:  c0008000
   Loading Standalone Program ... OK
OK
```

I tried the following commands to be located at address 0xC0008000 in "uimage":

```
mov pc, lr (ARM code)
bx lr (ARM code)
bx lr (Thumb code)
```

These commands should simply return (depending on ARM or Thumb mode being active). However all three commands result in U-Boot hanging so no more output is done after the last "OK".

Why does U-Boot hang?

Comment: In U-Boot, "standalone" means a binary image, such as the "hello_world.bin" example. Such loaded binaries are executed with the `go` command.  Loaded images/files executed using the `bootm` command must have the U-Boot wrapper installed, are typically OS kernels and can have special processing performed prior to execution.  See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15340089/how-to-run-custom-kernel-on-beaglebone/15375308#15375308). **Instead of specifying `linux` as the OS type in the mkimage command, try specifying `u-boot` or just omit an OS specification.**

Answer (score 3):

I found out the answer myself:

In the version of u-boot used on the EV3 brick there is a bug: The starting address that is already converted to little-endian is converted **twice** so the result is - of course - wrong.

By storing the number little endian in the file the output of u-boot will be wrong:

```
   Image Type:   ARM Linux Standalone Program (uncompressed)
   Data Size:    320 Bytes =  0.3 kB
   Load Address: c0008000
   Entry Point:  008000c0               <--- actually 0xC0008000!!!
   Loading Standalone Program ... OK
OK
U-Boot >
```

however booting will work. This bug only affects stand-alone programs and not Linux kernels.

My problem is that the program will possibly be published so it must work with both buggy and bug-fixed u-boot versions.

Therefore I think about loading the program to an address like

```
0xC00101C0
```

which is stored little and big endian the same way.