# how to boot kernel image in u-boot without 'bootm' command

Tags: qemu, u-boot

I am working on a simple OS for arm using qemu and uboot. I can load uboot fine and can load the image with using the 'bootm' command followed by the corresponding address. I want the kernel image to load automatically without having to call bootm. I added "#define CONFIG_BOOTCOMMAND "bootm 0x28124"" to the versatile.h file and it loads automatically, but the issue is that this address can change. I am using versatilepb and I thought it was strange that uboot is missing a lot of the commands that the documentations says it should have.

Comment: *"uboot is missing a lot of the commands that the documentations says it should have."* -- The available commands in a given copy of U-Boot are determined on how U-Boot was configured when built.  For "automatic" kernel/program execution, there is a countdown timer for "autoboot".  See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15340089/how-to-run-custom-kernel-on-beaglebone/15375308#15375308) for different ways to execute a kernel/program.  Note that commands can take variables as well as constants, so your `bootm 0x28124` could also be `setenv loadaddr 0x28124; bootm ${loadaddr}`.

Comment: I have the countdown timer and it auto booting by defining "#define CONFIG_BOOTCOMMAND "bootm 0x28124", but the issue is that the memory address changes dependent on the size of the kernel so I need the number to be dynamic. Would a bash script somehow solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

u-boot copy compressed kernel image onto memory and then jump to this kernel image's entry point. Then the kernel decompress and put kernel onto proper location at memory. 
As the offset of kernel entry to kernel image is fixed, and the location of compressed kernel is determined by u-boot and usually fixed. 
You wont need to change your bootm address when kernel size changes

Comment: Thank you, I actually figured it out and did something very similar to this. I concatenated the kernel image to a flash binary at a specific location and have bootm set at that location.