# How to boot bare board binary from U-Boot?

Tags: u-boot

How can we boot independent bare board binary(not standalone binary which runs using U-Boot environment and not linux kernel) from U-Boot. My requirement is to reinitialize the board and drivers using my binary...

I can replace the U-Boot in the boot medium(here NOR Flash) with my binary but my requirement is to not removing the U-boot from NOR flash and I should  load my binary from LAN network using "tftp" command.

Thanks and Regards, 
Veerendranath

Comment: Use U-Boot's `tftpboot` and `go` commands to execute any kind of standalone program.  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15340089/how-to-run-custom-kernel-on-beaglebone/15375308#15375308

Comment: @sawdust thanks for the reply... I am aware of these options. Here problem is when I use go command my program has to use U-Boot service functions(I mean standalone binaries will run in U-Boot environment)... But I want to take complete control from U-Boot as my binary is self-contained binary like kernel...But I can't boot using bootm or any other boot commands provided by U-Boot as my binary is not in kernel format...... Please let me know if you have any idea how accomplish it with out customizing the U-Boot....

Answer (score 4):

> How to boot bare board binary from U-Boot?

Use U-Boot's `go` command to execute any kind of standalone program.

> How can we boot independent bare board binary(not standalone binary which runs using U-Boot environment and not linux kernel) from U-Boot.

Use U-Boot's `go` command to execute any kind of standalone program.

> ... I should load my binary from LAN network using "tftp" command.

Use U-Boot's `tftpboot` and `go` commands to execute any kind of standalone program.  (The abbreviated `tftp` command has been deprecated now that there's also a `tftpput` command.)

> Here problem is when I use go command my program has to use U-Boot service functions(I mean standalone binaries will run in U-Boot environment)...

You're misinformed, there is no requirement that you have to "*use U-Boot service functions*".
Build your standalone program independently of U-Boot, and it will execute completely independent of U-Boot.

> But I can't boot using bootm or any other boot commands provided by U-Boot as my binary is not in kernel format.

There is no *"kernel format"*; that's why U-Boot uses the `mkimage` wrapper to identify binaries.
The `bootm` command is designed specifically for the booting requirements of OSes such as the Linux kernel (e.g. a buffer containing the command line parameters) by specifying the characteristics of the binary.
Use U-Boot's `go` command to execute any kind of simple, standalone program.

If you have issues executing your binary when using the `go` command, then the problem lies with your program, e.g. taking control of the processor and initializing its C environment.

**ADDENDUM**
When I use the term *standalone* program, I'm referring to the [generic definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standalone_program) (aka bare-metal), and not the [U-Boot-specific definition](http://www.denx.de/wiki/view/DULG/UBootStandalone) related to its **examples/** directory.
FWIW I have used the `go` command for both kinds of "standalone" programs.
U-Boot describes its "standalone" as

```
 * "Standalone Programs" are directly runnable in the environment
 *   provided by U-Boot; it is expected that (if they behave
 *   well) you can continue to work in U-Boot after return from
 *   the Standalone Program.
```

Note that the use of the U-Boot environment is optional.
A standalone program is not required to use the U-Boot environment, especially if there is no intention of returning back to U-Boot.
There is nothing in U-Boot to detect or restrict the behavior of a standalone program.

If you cannot get your standalone program to work with the `go` command, then the problem lies with your program, and not the `go` command.
The `go` command merely transfers control (i.e. a branch instruction to the specified memory location), and places no restrictions or requirements whatsoever on that code (other than what is sensible for operation of the system).

Use an in-circuit emulator (ICE) or JTAG debugger to resolve problems with your code, especially when your program does not use the existing stack.

**ADDENDUM 2**
Instead of the ambiguous `go` command, the `mkimage` wrapper does provide for the `standalone` image-type for use with the `bootm` command.
See [Creating a bare metal boot image](http://opencores.org/or1k/U-Boot), but don't expect different results from a `go` command.
The advantages of using a wrapper and `bootm` over `go` is that the downloaded image (a uImage file) can be:

- identified/verified with the `iminfo` command,
- compressed (e.g. gzip, bzip2, lzo) or uncompressed.

Comment: I already tried to start my binary using go command but didn't work...and here the primary requirement of my binary is to take control of the processor and re-initializing the controllers..
and regarding standalone programs you can check this https://compulab.co.il/workspace/mediawiki/index.php5/U-Boot:_Images

Comment: *"the primary requirement of my binary is to take control of the processor and re-initializing the controllers"* -- Beware that there are restrictions as to what your program can *"re-initialize"*.  Your program is already loaded and executing in DRAM, so any clocks that would affect DRAM timing cannot be modified,

Comment: *"I already tried to start my binary using go command but didn't work"* -- Then you're asking the wrong question. **There is no alternate U-Boot command that will produce better or different results.** You actually have a problem about standalone programming, and that should be your question. So since this is really a programming issue, you should be posting your code and details on how you compile and link it.

Answer (score 0):

1. You can create the boot.bin with fsbl, bitstream, uboot.elf and you applications. Then flash in the QSPI flash and choose to boot from it.
2. Or you can boot from TFTP. Here you need to create the boot.bin just with fsb, bitstream, and uboot.elf. You need the change the uboot header file to force it boot from tftp like tftpboot 0x0 hello.elf. Once booted it will grab the elf/bin file with tftp and boot the board with bootelf or go command.
3. The same you can boot from SD card if there is one.