# U-boot, Qemu and baremetal

Tags: qemu, u-boot, bare-metal

I was reading this:
https://balau82.wordpress.com/2010/03/10/u-boot-for-arm-on-qemu/

#### Context:

Baremtal programming

#### Foreword:

- OSX El Capitan, Qemu 2.2.1, U-boot 2016-07
- We cannot use the uboot.bin (no proper load and crash. Not to mention no Uboot prompt). I think it is OK for older uboot version though.
- I created a baremetal assembly program that executes just fine in qemu alone (set the registers to some values and the qemu monitor confirmed those values)
- It fails to be executed when I mix it with UBoot
- I need uboot to test UART, have a proper DRAM and so on. I don't want to write a new bootloader for those partly undocumented stuffs.

#### The process:

- QEMU + baremetal application (Makefile below):

  ```
  prepimg:
      ~/Downloads/gcc-arm-none-eabi-5_4-2016q3/bin/arm-none-eabi-as -g comm.ml -o comm.o
      ~/Downloads/gcc-arm-none-eabi-5_4-2016q3/bin/arm-none-eabi-ld -T test.ld comm.o -o test.elf
      ~/Downloads/gcc-arm-none-eabi-5_4-2016q3/bin/arm-none-eabi-objcopy -O binary test.elf test.bin
  mkimg:
      mkimage -A arm -C none -T kernel -O linux -d test.bin -a 0x0010000 -e 0x0010000 test.uimg
  launch_test:
      qemu-system-arm -m 128M -M vexpress-a9 -nographic -monitor telnet:127.0.0.1:1234,server,nowait -kernel test.uimg
  ```

It works. Code is executed at the correct address (r15 proves it).

- QEMU + baremetal + U-boot

  ```
  prepimg:
      ~/Downloads/gcc-arm-none-eabi-5_4-2016q3/bin/arm-none-eabi-as -g comm.ml -o comm.o
      ~/Downloads/gcc-arm-none-eabi-5_4-2016q3/bin/arm-none-eabi-ld -T test.ld comm.o -o test.elf
      ~/Downloads/gcc-arm-none-eabi-5_4-2016q3/bin/arm-none-eabi-objcopy -O binary test.elf test.bin
  mkimg:
      mkimage -A arm -C none -T kernel -O linux -d test.bin -a 0x0010000 -e 0x0010000 test.uimg

  cat_them:
      cat u-boot-2016.07/u-boot test.uimg > u-boot-2016.07/flash.bin

  launch_qemu:
      qemu-system-arm -m 128M -M vexpress-a9 -nographic -monitor telnet:127.0.0.1:1234,server,nowait -kernel u-boot-2016.07/flash.bin
  ```

Then, I get:

```
Wrong Image Format for bootm command
ERROR: can't get kernel image!
```

#### Trials:

- I tried to modify the entry point and load address of my code to 0x80008000, 0x8000 but still the same thing.
- I spent hours trying to display different regions of the memory (with the u-boot md tool), looking for my code, no luck.

I don't know what is going on.

Comment: How does using the `tftp` command resolve all of your issues?  E.G. see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35362242/how-to-boot-bare-board-binary-from-u-boot/35385537#35385537  BTW learn the proper spelling of U-Boot; you use at least 4 spelling variations, all are incorrect.  (At least you didn't use the atrociously ignorant "uBoot".)

Answer (score 1):

Finally,

I d/l my file via tftp and got the job done.