# It possible to boot freertos over network?

Tags: xilinx, u-boot, freertos, zynq

some words to my system.

Im work on the Xilinx development-board zc706.
The basic example of freertos are running.

Now the question is: How i can boot the application over network?
A freertos application is a bare-metal approach.
Typically a loader like u-boot is been used, but the examples I find, was only for the linux use-case.

Addition:
With the XMD console its possible to load the u-boot in the memory

```
XMD% source ps7_init.tcl
XMD% ps7_init
XMD% dow u-boot
Processor started. Type "stop" to stop processor
Processor Stop Condition Unknown
Processor Reset .... DONE
Downloading Program -- u-boot
    section, .text: 0x04000000-0x040524d7
    section, efi_runtime_text: 0x040524d8-0x040524fb
    section, .rodata: 0x04052500-0x040650d1
    section, .hash: 0x040650d4-0x040650ff
    section, .dtb.init.rodata: 0x04065100-0x0406866f
    section, .data: 0x04068670-0x0406b31b
    section, .got.plt: 0x0406b31c-0x0406b327
    section, efi_runtime_data: 0x0406b328-0x0406b3ff
    section, .u_boot_list: 0x0406b400-0x0406c71f
    section, .rel.dyn: 0x0406c720-0x04077d5f
    section, .bss: 0x0406c720-0x040ad29f
Download Progress..10.20.30.40.50.60.70.80.90.Done
Setting PC with Program Start Address 0x04000000
XMD% run

RUNNING> 0
XMD%
```

The result ist seen with on a com port:

```
U-Boot 2017.01-00012-g374a838 (May 29 2017 - 17:55:04 +0200)

Model: Zynq ZC706 Development Board
Board: Xilinx Zynq
I2C:   ready
DRAM:  ECC disabled 1 GiB
MMC:   sdhci@e0100000: 0 (SD)
SF: Detected s25fl128s_64k with page size 512 Bytes, erase size 128 KiB, total 32 MiB
*** Warning - bad CRC, using default environment

In:    serial@e0001000
Out:   serial@e0001000
Err:   serial@e0001000
Model: Zynq ZC706 Development Board
Board: Xilinx Zynq
Net:   ZYNQ GEM: e000b000, phyaddr 7, interface rgmii-id
eth0: ethernet@e000b000
Hit any key to stop autoboot:  0 
Device: sdhci@e0100000
Manufacturer ID: 27
OEM: 5048
Name: SD16G 
Tran Speed: 50000000
Rd Block Len: 512
SD version 3.0
High Capacity: Yes
Capacity: 14.5 GiB
Bus Width: 4-bit
Erase Group Size: 512 Bytes
reading uEnv.txt
** Unable to read file uEnv.txt **
Copying Linux from SD to RAM...
reading uImage
** Unable to read file uImage **
Zynq>
```

Addition:
I have build the FSBL with the flag FSBL_DEBUG:
(Project -> Properties -> C/C++ Build -> Settings -> ARM gcc compiler -> Symbols)
The I build the bin file only with the boot loader partion and put it on the SD card:
Xilinx Tools->Create Boot Image

Addition:
The problem is, that the SDK needs a file with name u-boot.elf. The extention was not there after the build of u-boot.

So now I have a TFTP-Server running on my host and the u-boot find the uEnv.txt file, but the cmd in this file doesn't run:

How I can setup the u-boot an give the right loadAddress to loadthe freeRTos elf-file?

The tftpboot cmd seems to be:

```
tftpboot [loadAddress] [bootfilename]
e.g.
tftpboot 0x80400000 vlm-boards/14726/uImage
```

What is the load address of the zc706 board?

Addition:

The connection an the download with the TFTP-server seems to work:
But after starting with the "go" cmd a reset occur.

```
Zynq> setenv ipaddr 192.168.150.101 
Zynq> setenv netmask 255.255.255.0
Zynq> setenv gatewayip 192.168.150.1
Zynq> serverip=192.168.150.100
Zynq> ping 192.168.150.100                   
Using ethernet@e000b000 device
host 192.168.150.100 is alive
Zynq> tftpboot 0x8000 FreeRTOS_HelloWorld.elf
Using ethernet@e000b000 device
TFTP from server 192.168.150.100; our IP address is 192.168.150.101
Filename 'FreeRTOS_HelloWorld.elf'.
Load address: 0x8000
Loading: ###############
         2.8 MiB/s
done
Bytes transferred = 205675 (3236b hex)
Zynq> go 0x8000
## Starting application at 0x00008000 ...
undefined instruction
pc : [<0000fa60>]          lr : [<3ff443c4>]
reloc pc : [<c40cda60>]    lr : [<040023c4>]
sp : 3eb20cf4  ip : 0000001c     fp : 3ff4437c
r10: 3eb1f9b0  r9 : 3eb21ee8     r8 : 3ffaef30
r7 : 00000000  r6 : 00008000     r5 : 00000002  r4 : 3eb2f9b4
r3 : 00008000  r2 : 3eb2f9b4     r1 : 3eb2f9b4  r0 : 00001084
Flags: nZcv  IRQs off  FIQs off  Mode SVC_32
Resetting CPU ...

resetting ...
```

Thx in advance

Comment: Is it running on ARM or on FPGA? You may use examples for linux boot and replace linux image with freertos image.

Comment: At first on ARM

Comment: As I understand til now: 
1. create a FSBL 
2.1 download the uboot sources 
2.2 configure the uboot for the zc706 board
2.3 build the uboot

With replacement of the linux image, are other changes had to be made for an freertos elf file?

Comment: You'll likely want 'bootelf' to start your application, once loaded into memory.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35362242/how-to-boot-bare-board-binary-from-u-boot and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15340089/how-to-run-custom-kernel-on-beaglebone

Comment: At which address should the u-boot load and start (tftpboot 0x.... xxx.bin; go 0x....) the application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is:
The Xilinx SDK supply as an output an Elf-File, which the u-boot understands:

```
tftpboot 0x000000 FreeRTOS_ZC706_HelloWorld.elf
bootelf 0x0
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

tftpboot 0x0 hello.efl; bootelf 0x0;

works in Uboot 2019.2 version and FreeRTOS.elf.

For the other core, you need to convert it to bin format using arm-none-eabi-objcopy -O binary hello.elf hello.bin. tftpboot it under the correct memory postion. And fire it up in the CPU0 code.